# how to display <li> with certain order in desktop and another order for responsive mode tablet, smartphone, ...etc?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If I have this navbar (arabic navbar):
you will notice that i reversed the order so it will show in a right Arabic order with
(Home-الرئيسية) 
at the bottom (which in this case is right side), but when you change the viewport it will make no sense, because it will start with 
(contact us-إتصل بنا).
So how to fix this?

```html
<div id="navbar" class=" nav-link navbar-collapse navbar-left collapse">
            <ul class="nav nav-link navbar-nav navbar-left">
              <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="press"><span>اتصل بنا - Contact us</span></a></li>
              <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="pricing"><span>أسعارنا - Prices</span></a></li>
              <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="testimonials"><span>عملائنا - Our customers</span></a></li>
              <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="features"><span>معرض اعمالنا - Gallery</span></a></li>
              <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="services"><span>خدماتنا - Services</span></a></li>
              <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="about"><span>من نحن - About</span></a></li>     
              <li class="active nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="home"><span>الرئيسية - Home</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

Comment: How are you changing the viewport ? Can you share that code - It seems fine on my side, it always has Home at the bottom

Comment: @nikhil-nanjappa i need to display the <li> with certain order in desktop and another order for responsive mode tablet, smartphone, ...etc

Answer (score 0):

You could rotate the parent element 180deg and then rotate the children elements -180deg.

```css
ul {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
ul > li {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" class=" nav-link navbar-collapse navbar-left collapse">
            <ul class="nav nav-link navbar-nav navbar-left">
              <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="press"><span>اتصل بنا - Contact us</span></a></li>
              <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="pricing"><span>أسعارنا - Prices</span></a></li>
              <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="testimonials"><span>عملائنا - Our customers</span></a></li>
              <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="features"><span>معرض اعمالنا - Gallery</span></a></li>
              <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="services"><span>خدماتنا - Services</span></a></li>
              <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="about"><span>من نحن - About</span></a></li>     
              <li class="active nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="home"><span>الرئيسية - Home</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

Alternatively, you could use flex boxes along with the order property.

Although this isn't technically reversing the order, you could also use counter-increment along with a psuedo element.

Example Here

`ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    counter-reset:item 6;
}`
`ul > li {
    counter-increment:item -1;
}`
`ul > li:after {
    content: counter(item);
}`

Comment: can you please elaborate on this 
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    counter-reset:item 6;
} ul > li {
    counter-increment:item -1;
} ul > li:after {
    content: counter(item);
}

Comment: it's not working for me, i need to display the <li> with certain order in desktop and another order for responsive mode tablet, smartphone, ...etc

Answer (score 0):

Use `direction: rtl;` to `#navbar` like:

```
#navbar {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

Look at the snippet below:

```css
#navbar {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" class=" nav-link navbar-collapse navbar-left collapse">
            <ul class="nav nav-link navbar-nav navbar-left">
              <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="press"><span>اتصل بنا - Contact us</span></a></li>
              <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="pricing"><span>أسعارنا - Prices</span></a></li>
              <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="testimonials"><span>عملائنا - Our customers</span></a></li>
              <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="features"><span>معرض اعمالنا - Gallery</span></a></li>
              <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="services"><span>خدماتنا - Services</span></a></li>
              <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="about"><span>من نحن - About</span></a></li>     
              <li class="active nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="home"><span>الرئيسية - Home</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: not what i need, i need to display the <li> with certain order in desktop and another order for responsive mode tablet, smartphone, ...etc

Answer (score 0):

you can put navigation in both top /left . Follow this example

```css
.nav-side-menu {
overflow: auto;
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 200;
background-color: #2e353d;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
width: 300px;
height: 100%;
color: #e1ffff;
}
.nav-side-menu .brand {
    background-color: #23282e;
    line-height: 50px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
    display: none;
}
.nav-side-menu ul,
.nav-side-menu li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*
      .collapsed{
         .arrow:before{
                   font-family: FontAwesome;
                   content: "\f053";
                   display: inline-block;
                   padding-left:10px;
                   padding-right: 10px;
                   vertical-align: middle;
                   float:right;
              }
       }
  */
}
.nav-side-menu ul :not(collapsed) .arrow:before,
.nav-side-menu li :not(collapsed) .arrow:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f078";
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .active,
.nav-side-menu li .active {
    border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
    background-color: #4f5b69;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active {
    color: #d19b3d;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active a,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active a {
    color: #d19b3d;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li {
    background-color: #181c20;
    border: none;
    line-height: 28px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:hover,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #020203;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:before,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f105";
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.nav-side-menu li {
    padding-left: 0px;
    border-left: 3px solid #2e353d;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #23282e;
}
.nav-side-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e1ffff;
}
.nav-side-menu li a i {
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.nav-side-menu li:hover {
    border-left: 3px solid #d19b3d;
    background-color: #4f5b69;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .nav-side-menu {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
        top: 10px;
        z-index: 10 !important;
        padding: 3px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        color: #000;
        width: 40px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .brand {
        text-align: left !important;
        font-size: 22px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        line-height: 50px !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
    .nav-side-menu .menu-list .menu-content {
        display: block;
    }
    #main {
        width:calc(100% - 300px);
        float: right;
    }
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title>Image Uploader</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar"  role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header" id="fkj">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Book Shopping</a>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Add Products</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">My Cart</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="adminPanel.html">Admin Panel</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>
        <div class="col-md-2"style="margin-left:0px;border-right:1px solid #cacdd1;">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li><a href="#">Image Upload</a></li>
                <hr style="margin:2px;">
                <li><a href="#">Menu Number1</a></li>
                <hr style="margin:2px;">
                <li><a href="#">Menu Number2</a></li>
                <hr style="margin:2px;">
                <li><a href="#">Menu Number3</a></li>
                <hr style="margin:2px;">
                <li><a href="#">Menu Number4</a></li>
                <hr style="margin:2px;">
                <li><a href="#">Menu Number5</a></li>
                <hr style="margin:2px;">
                <li><a href="#">Menu Number6</a></li>
                <hr style="margin:2px;">
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8" align="center">
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                Your Photo: <input type="file" name="photo" size="25" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>

        <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: not what i need, i need to display the <li> with certain order in desktop and another order for responsive mode tablet, smartphone, ...etc

Answer (score 0):

If you require so much flexibility then the best & recommended solution I would suggest is **Flexbox** - Its just a CSS3 feature not any framework or such, so can be implemented anytime.

**The solution**

[Check the Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yn16cooL/1/) (Reduce the panel size to see the affect on smaller width devices)

Your magic flex property is **`order`**. [Read about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)

> Elements are laid out in the ascending order of the `order` value. Elements with the same `order` value are laid out in the order in which they appear in the source code.

So you navbar CSS can look like:

```
.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li.nav-link:nth-child(1) {
    order: 5; //this will appear on top since it has highest `order` value
}

li.nav-link:nth-child(2) {
    order: 4; //this will appear second in the list
}

li.nav-link:nth-child(3) {
    order: 3;
}

li.nav-link:nth-child(4) {
    order: 2;
}

li.nav-link:nth-child(5) {
    order: 1;
}

li.nav-link:nth-child(6) {
    order: 0;
}

li.nav-link:nth-child(7) {
    order: -1; //this will appear last as it has least `order` value
}
```

And on a smaller/smartphone device you can rearrange the order like so using `media queries`:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  //`order` values have been changed
  li.nav-link:nth-child(1) {
    order: -1;
  }

  li.nav-link:nth-child(2) {
    order: 0;
  }

  li.nav-link:nth-child(3) {
    order: 1;
  }

  li.nav-link:nth-child(4) {
    order: 2;
  }

  li.nav-link:nth-child(5) {
    order: 3;
  }

  li.nav-link:nth-child(6) {
    order: 4;
  }

  li.nav-link:nth-child(7) {
    order: 5;
  }
}
```

**Advantage**

This way you have total control of EACH of your list items & arrange them wherever you want in any device you want.

---

```css
.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li.nav-link:nth-child(1) {
    order: 5;
}

li.nav-link:nth-child(2) {
    order: 4;
}

li.nav-link:nth-child(3) {
    order: 3;
}

li.nav-link:nth-child(4) {
    order: 2;
}

li.nav-link:nth-child(5) {
    order: 1;
}

li.nav-link:nth-child(6) {
    order: 0;
}

li.nav-link:nth-child(7) {
    order: -1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  li.nav-link:nth-child(1) {
    order: -1;
  }

  li.nav-link:nth-child(2) {
    order: 0;
  }

  li.nav-link:nth-child(3) {
    order: 1;
  }

  li.nav-link:nth-child(4) {
    order: 2;
  }

  li.nav-link:nth-child(5) {
    order: 3;
  }

  li.nav-link:nth-child(6) {
    order: 4;
  }

  li.nav-link:nth-child(7) {
    order: 5;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar" class=" nav-link navbar-collapse navbar-left collapse">
  <ul class="nav nav-link navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="press"><span>اتصل بنا - Contact us</span></a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="pricing"><span>أسعارنا - Prices</span></a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="testimonials"><span>عملائنا - Our customers</span></a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="features"><span>معرض اعمالنا - Gallery</span></a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="services"><span>خدماتنا - Services</span></a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="about"><span>من نحن - About</span></a></li>     
    <li class="active nav-link"><a href="#" data-nav-section="home"><span>الرئيسية - Home</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```